# Html site deployed on google bucket giving error

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, godaddy-api, google-bucket

I deployed my html website using gcp bucket and godaddy. It was working fine but just few days back it starts giving this error on browser

```
{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Could not resolve / to a method.","status":"UNIMPLEMENTED"}}
```

When i check on bucket that url is working fine
https://storage.cloud.google.com/www.autodealersbuddy.com/index.html

How can i fix it?

Comment: See [Google Cloud Storage Hosting w CI/CD and BigQuery Hit History Done In 5 Minutes!](https://medium.com/@ronnieroyston/google-cloud-storage-website-w-ci-cd-and-bigquery-hit-history-database-in-5-minutes-99badb282c3b),
Google Cloud Storage, HTTPS Load Balancing, Cloud CDN, Source Repositories, Cloud Build, Cloud Logging, and BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

[Google's guidance](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http#cname) is to create a `CNAME` record for your domain pointed at `c.storage.googleapis.com`, and to configure your bucket containing the static site's assets with a name matching the FQDN you've set up (the latter of which you seem to have done).

Counter to this, the DNS record for your `www` subdomain (at least, the one that my local DNS server has for it) is pointing to an arbitrary IP:

```
% dig +noall +answer +multiline www.autodealersbuddy.com any
www.autodealersbuddy.com. 1800 IN A 34.120.131.3
```

A similar `A` record (with a lower TTL value) appears in your root zone as well:

```
% dig +noall +answer +multiline autodealersbuddy.com any
autodealersbuddy.com.   600 IN A 34.120.131.3
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN NS ns49.domaincontrol.com.
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN NS ns50.domaincontrol.com.
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN SOA ns49.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. (
                2023061803 ; serial
                28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                600        ; minimum (10 minutes)
                )
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN MX 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN MX 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all"
autodealersbuddy.com.   3600 IN TXT "google-site-verification=v1ytZYFq8PW919_c8YM8FtzYfOd7R0SkSEDxzapfm8Q"
```

Cursory research was inconclusive as to what exactly this IP maps to or where it comes from. If this news is surprising to you, you may want to invest some time to investigating whether the records were changed without your authorization, possibly in some form of DNS hijacking attack.

In any event, an update to your DNS settings to replace the `A` record that's currently there with the proper `CNAME` in accordance with Google's documentation is in order.

I confirmed this is the culprit by manually setting this `CNAME` record in my local DNS server and reloading your page, which then shows up as one might expect:

[image: Target site properly loaded]

Comment: Thank you for reply :)
Right now its set to 34.120.131.3 in godaddy

Comment: So i need to set it to c.storage.googleapis.com? @esqew

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you need to replace the existing `A` record with a `CNAME` record with that value. Follow the instructions Google provides (linked in my answer) along with the documentation your DNS provider provides on how to accomplish this. You won’t be able to set an `A` record to something that’s not an IP address (or rather, you shouldn’t, as it won’t function properly as an `A` record).